# node_modules/bingmaps/types/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bing-maps

I am using official npm of bingmaps with angular 7 (cli).

I added done the configuration as mentioned in the documentation of npm
I am currently loading basic bing map.
In my component.ts file I have added below line as compiler was giving error if not used this line ('Microsoft' is not defined)

```
import { } from '../../../../../../node_modules/bingmaps/types/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All';
```

now when i am compiling the code I am getting another error as **Microsoft.Maps.All is not a module.**

Any idea about this? is this the issue related to angular CLI?
I have referred below link as well but not getting what they are trying to say.
[git link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Bing-Maps-V8-TypeScript-Definitions/issues/15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to import a module, consider to import the library instead:

```
import 'bingmaps';
```

Another option to surpass this compilation error would be to include a dependency on  `@types/bingmaps` package via `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    //..
    "types": ["bingmaps"]
}
```

Here is an example on how to utilize [`bingmaps` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bingmaps) in Angular2+ application:

`map.component.ts` file:

```
/// <reference types="@types/bingmaps" />

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { BingMapsAPILoader } from "./BingMapsAPILoader";

@Component({
  selector: "app-map",
  templateUrl: "./map.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor (loader: BingMapsAPILoader) {
    loader.load("bingAPIReady").then(() => this.initMap());
  }

  protected initMap() {
    const options: Microsoft.Maps.IMapLoadOptions = {
      center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.60357, -122.32945),
      credentials:
        "--your Bing Maps API Key goes here--"
    };

    const map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
  }
}
```

map.component.html file

```
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

where `BingMapsAPILoader` is a service for loading Bing Maps library:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class BingMapsAPILoader {

  private getNativeWindow(): any {
    return window;
  }
  private getNativeDocument(): any {
    return document;
  }

  public load(callbackName: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
      const script = this.getNativeDocument().createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      script.src = 'https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=bingAPIReady';
      this.getNativeWindow()[callbackName] = () => {
        resolve();
      };
      script.onerror = (error: Event) => {
        reject(error);
      };
      this.getNativeDocument().body.appendChild(script);
    });
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag5tkt) for your reference